# get the country name from Google geocode reverse API, android

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding

I want to get the country name of a given latitude and longitude. I am using Google Geocode API. I am using the following query :

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat1+","+lng1+"&sensor=true_or_false"
```

the result of the JSON is like this:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": street_address,
    "formatted_address": "275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "275-291",
      "short_name": "275-291",
      "types": street_number
    }, {
      "long_name": "Bedford Ave",
      "short_name": "Bedford Ave",
      "types": route
    }, {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "New York",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Brooklyn",
      "short_name": "Brooklyn",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Kings",
      "short_name": "Kings",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "NY",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "11211",
      "short_name": "11211",
      "types": postal_code
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 40.7142298,
        "lng": -73.9614669
      },
      "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 40.7110822,
          "lng": -73.9646145
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 40.7173774,
          "lng": -73.9583193
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

how to get the country name from this result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new Location API to do this. Here's a tutorial for the same - https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html. For the country name, just call `getCountryName()` on the `Address` object.

Comment: I used it before but it doesn't work in my country, so I want to using Google Geocode API instead

Comment: In that case, you'll have to do something dirty. Parse the JSON using something like GSON and get the name by parsing the value of formatted_address value

Comment: I have never heard of GSON :(
how could I use it in this query

Comment: GSON is a library by Google for serializing/deserializing JSON (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). See ex here https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples

Answer (score 0):

```
Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(this);
            List<Address> addresses;
            try {
                addresses = gCoder.getFromLocation(clat, clng, 5);
                Log.e("get adderess", addresses + "");
                if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                    addres = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    System.out.print(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

(or)

try even with this

```
public static String getCountryName(Context context, double latitude, double longitude) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    Address result;
    if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
        return addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I used it before but it doesn't work in my country, so I want to using Google Geocode API instead

Comment: i have updated the code ...you can try with this..with Geocod